# HTTP 401 Unauthorized when not using HTTP basic auth?

Tags: rest, authentication, http-status-codes

When building a REST API that doesn't use [HTTP basic authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) (but something else like an api-key) and the client provides invalid credentials, what HTTP Status Code are you supposed to return? 401 Unauthorized or 403 Forbidden?

The [IANA HTTP Status Code Registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml) lists [RFC7235, Section 3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-3.1) as responsible for "401 Unauthorized", where it states:

> The server generating a 401 response MUST send a WWW-Authenticate header field

Does that mean that a REST API should only ever return a 401 when using HTTP basic authentication but not when for example using authentication via an api-key?

Django [seems](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication#unauthorized-and-forbidden-responses) to agree:

> HTTP 401 responses must always include a WWW-Authenticate header, that instructs the client how to authenticate. HTTP 403 responses do not include the WWW-Authenticate header.
>
> The kind of response that will be used depends on the authentication scheme.

While Richardson [seems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959947/whats-an-appropriate-http-status-code-to-return-by-a-rest-api-service-for-a-val/1960453#1960453) to disagree:

> **401 (“Unauthorized”)**
> Importance: High.
> The client tried to operate on a protected resource without providing the proper authentication credentials. It may have provided the wrong credentials, or none at all.
> The credentials may be a username and password, an API key, or an authentication
> token—whatever the service in question is expecting. It’s common for a client to make
> a request for a URI and accept a 401 just so it knows what kind of credentials to send
> and in what format. [...]

Comment: You should, for various reasons, avoid using API keys in headers. See my discussion here: http://soabits.blogspot.dk/2014/02/api-authentication-considerations-and.html and Eran Hammers discussion here: http://hueniverse.com/2010/09/29/oauth-bearer-tokens-are-a-terrible-idea/

Comment: Just found what is basically the same question. It didn't turn up in my previous searches: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17687876/authorization-in-restful-http-api-401-www-authenticate

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are assuming that the www-authenticate value needs to be basic.  You can return a different value like "API-key" as the type of auth that needs to happen.  So feel free to return 401 and www-authenticate header with some other value.  You can even return multiple headers with different values indicating the different types of authentication that your app supports.

Comment: What spec describes valid values for `www-authenticate`? Is there a list or some de-facto standardized values?

Comment: There is a (very new) list here: http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-authschemes/http-authschemes.xhtml.