# What WWW-Authenticate header should a http server return in a 401 response when using form-based authentication?

Tags: rest, http, authentication, http-status-code-401

I have a web application with a Javascript part running on the browser. That frontend uses several HTTP endpoints (more or less REST). The frontend must be able to distinguish between `401` and `403` responses and must not receive the `3xx` redirects usually used for human users.

Authorization is done with a plain form login (no Javascript involved there), then a session cookie is used (for both "REST" and normal requests).

What would be a correct value for the `WWW-Authenticate` header value?

- From [RFC 7235](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-4.1): "A server generating a 401 (Unauthorized) response MUST send a WWW-Authenticate header field containing at least one challenge."
- The [Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) Authentication Scheme Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-authschemes/http-authschemes.xhtml) does not list any scheme for form-based authentication.

See also:

- [HTTP 401 Unauthorized when not using HTTP basic auth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24553631/http-401-unauthorized-when-not-using-http-basic-auth)
- [Authorization in RESTful HTTP API, 401 WWW-Authenticate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17687876/authorization-in-restful-http-api-401-www-authenticate)

Comment: Just invented the "FormBased" scheme. Only the IANA registration pending ;-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since there is no standard challenge for this type of authentication, you are (as you predicted yourself) inventing your own.

I don't think there is a standard mechanism for specifying vendor tokens here, so I think the best thing you can do is use a token that's unlikely to clash with anything else.

Amazon has done this with `AWS`, and there's many others. My recommendation would be to use something like `productname-schemename`, for example `acme-webauth`.

Answer (score 6):

> What would be a correct value for the `WWW-Authenticate` header value?

There's no point in returning [`401`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-3.1) and [`WWW-Authenticate`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-4.1) when you are not using HTTP Authentication as described in the [RFC 7235](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235). In HTTP Authentication, the client is expected to send the credentials in the [`Authorization`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-4.2) header of the request with an [authentication scheme](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-authschemes/http-authschemes.xhtml) token.

If you want to send the credentials in the request payload using [`POST`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3), the [`403`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.3) status code you be more suitable to indicate that the server has refused the request.

Answer (score 1):

**In theory** you should respond

```
HTTP/1.x 401 Unauthorized
WWW-Authenticate: cookie; cookie-name=my-session-cookie-name
```

**However, real world internet browsers (user agents) do not really support this** and in my experience the least bad option is to use HTTP status `403` for all of "Access Denied", "Unauthorized" or "Not allowed". If you have a REST service that's **accessed with non-browser user-agents only**, you could just follow the spec and return the above headers.

Also note that as described in RFC 7231 section 6.5.4 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.4) the server can respond with 404 for both "Access Denied" and "Not Found" so following should be okay for all user agents (browsers and standalone clients):

```
403 Unauthorized or Not allowed

404 Access Denied or Not Found
```

Or, you can just use `400` for any case because that should cause browser do fallback to generic error handling case. The HTTP status code 401 is especially problematic because it historically meant (at least in practice) that `Basic Realm` authentication is in use and the submitted HTTP header `Authorization` was not accepted. Because you cannot submit the session cookie via that header with commonly available browsers, those browsers have trouble handling 401 correctly when you use cookies for authentication. (According to the spec, [HTTP 401 `MUST` include header `WWW-Authenticate`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-3.1) which should be used to figure out correct handling by the user agent but this doesn't seem to happen in reality with browsers.)

Comment: For additional details, see https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-broyer-http-cookie-auth-00.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no HTTP authentication scheme for form based authentication.
Browsers implement basic, digest, etc. by showing a pop up where you can enter credentials.

Comment: That's basically what I said with "The Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) Authentication Scheme Registry does not list any scheme for form-based authentication.", isn't it? And now, should I just invent a scheme? I guess I am not the first one with this problem. Browsers host Javascript apps and those may understand more things than the browser itself. So, if no formal spec, maybe a best practice?

Comment: `WWW-Authenticate` is not used with Form-based authentication - period. You will have to use 403 instead of 401

Comment: If you "invent" your "FormBased" scheme you have still the problem that you are sending e.g. a POST request with some application/x-www-form-urlencoded credentials which is wrong and not expected. You must use the WWW-Authenticate request header to provide credentials and you have to send them along with each following request as in HTTP the communication must be stateless.

Comment: @spaceone I don't think RFC7235 states that a WWW-Authenticate header requires authentication to be done with the Authorization header. I couldn't find any language supporting this.

Comment: From my point of view the WWW-Autentication header just indicates authentication is required, and there's a token indicating what protocol should be used. The authentication semantics depend on the token.

Comment: Reading RFC further, it actually specifically states that the Authorization header is "usually, but not necessarily", but let me know if your interpretation is different.